# Populate python array without double loop

Tags: python, loops, pandas, correlation

Can anyone advise me on how to use pandas more efficiently, currently I am doing the following to find out the correlation of two items but this isn't very fast.

```
for i in range(0, df.shape[0]):
    for j in range(0, df.shape[0]):
        if i<j:
            ##  get the weights
            wgt_i = dataWgt_df.ix[df.index[i]][0]
            wgt_j = dataWgt_df.ix[df.index[j]][0]
            ##  get the std's
            std_i = dataSTD_df.loc[date][df.index[i]][0]
            std_j = dataSTD_df.loc[date][df.index[j]][0]
            ##  get the corvariance
            #print(cor.ix[df.index[i]][df.index[j]])
            cor = corr.ix[df.index[i]][df.index[j]]
            ##  create running total
            totalBottom = totalBottom + (wgt_i * wgt_j * std_i * std_j)
            totalTop = totalTop + (wgt_i * wgt_j * std_i * std_j * cor)
```

What I want to do is create an identity matrix like this

```
0  1  1  1  1
0  0  1  1  1
0  0  0  1  1
0  0  0  0  1
0  0  0  0  0
```

which I can then use to multiply over the various dataframes, wgt_i wgt_j std_i std_j this will create a dataframe for top and bottom which I can then sum using the sum function and get the result.

My main question here is how to create the identity dataframe quickly and then create the wgt_i etc dataframe as the rest is relatively straight forward.

Comment: An identity matrix contains 1 on the main diagonal and 0 everywhere else.

Comment: I am not an expert in Linear Algebra, but I can tell that it definitely is not an identity matrix...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a `pandas` expert, but it seems like it works well with `numpy`. Going with that assumption, here are a couple of things you can do with `numpy` to avoid the double nested loop.

1. Ian is correct; that's not an identity matrix. If you *do* want an identity matrix, you can simply use [`numpy.identity`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.identity.html#numpy.identity):

   ```
   import numpy
   numpy.identity(5)

   array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
          [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
          [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
          [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
          [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.]])
   ```
2. However, if you want the exact matrix you specified above, you can use [`numpy.eye`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.eye.html#numpy.eye):

   ```
   import numpy
   n = 5  # yields a 5x5 array; adjust to whatever size you want
   numpy.sum(numpy.eye(n, k=i) for i in range(1,n))

   array([[ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
          [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
          [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.],
          [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
          [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
   ```

Comment: thanks, apologies for the terrible use of terminology and I know it isn't an identity matrix but that solution is great!

Comment: @bpython No problem! If you like the answer, please mark it as the correct one. Or choose the other one if you like it better. =)

Answer (score 0):

This is not as short as the solution from @larsbutler, but much faster for large n:

```
import numpy as np

n = 5
M = np.zeros((n,n))
M[np.triu_indices_from(M)] = 1
M[np.diag_indices_from(M)] = 0
```

gives:

```
array([[ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```